# Javascript regex Currency symbol in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

so I have a formatting string that can be `$#,###.00` or `"£#,###.00`  and I would like to get the currency symbol form it here is the code that I'm using:

```
 currencySymbol =  format.match(/\p{Sc}/);
```

I would like currencySymbol to be equal to "$" or "£" but it's not working currencySymbol is null.

Comment: `format.charAt(0)` ?

Comment: not sure if it's always the first symbol for euros for example it's the last symbol

Comment: @HasseneBenammou does my answer below help you out?

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you are interested in finding the various currency symbols, take a look at CLDR. For example, http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr-aux/json/26/main/en/currencies.json .

If you want to add markups on the currency symbols, I can also help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an addon like [XregExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/).

Answer (score 20):

**Short answer**:

`/[\$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]/`

**Long answer**:

A JavaScript regular expression equivalent to `/\p{Sc}/` is:

```
ScRe = /[\$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]/

ScRe.test("$"); // true
ScRe.test("£"); // true
ScRe.test("€"); // true
```

The above has been generated by:

```
$ npm install regenerate
$ npm install unicode-7.0.0
$ node 
> regenerate().add(require('unicode-7.0.0/categories/Sc/symbols')).toString();
```

- https://github.com/mathiasbynens/regenerate
- https://github.com/mathiasbynens/unicode-7.0.0

Watch:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zi0w7J7MCrk

Answer (score 3):

`\p{Sc}` is PCRE regex property and Javascript doesn't support it.

In Javascript you need to use specific symbols in character class to match them like this:

```
/[$£]/
```

Comment: should I list all the currencies possible? because it can be anything.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, you will need to list all possible currencies in this character class in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this `/(kr|$|£|€)/`.

`currencySymbol =  format.match(/(kr|$|£|€)/);`