# Strip currency symbol

Tags: node.js, regex, currency

`$ 12,345,60`, `12 540 420 $`.. given currency strings with currency symbol that could be at the begging or at the end, I'd like to strip the currency symbol.

With the above examples, the output should be .. note that the currency symbol is not alway USD. it can be any symbol.

`$ 12,345,60 -> 12,345,60`

`12 540 420 € -> 12 540 420`

`12 456 700 -> 12 456 700`

The easiest way of course is to check if the first or the last character is digit and otherwise remove it. I was wondering if it can be done using regex or any other better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps do it this way ...

```js
let str = ['$ 12,345,60', '12 540 420 €', '12 456 700'];
str.forEach(e => {
  console.log(e.match(/\b[\d, ]+\b/g)[0]);
});
```

Comment: sorry .. I updated the question that the currency symbol can be any symbol not USD always

Comment: thanks for your answer .. I need more generic solution since the currency symbol can be any symbol and I'd like to avoid listing all possible symbols in [] clause ..

Answer (score 0):

To match any currency symbol in Javascript without any external library use this character class:

```
[$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]
```

You can search using this regex:

```
var currRE = /[$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]/;

var re = new RegExp("^\\s*" + currRE.source + "\\s*(\\d)|(\\d)\\s*" + 
         currRE.source + "\\s*$")
```

and replace it using:

```
'$1$2'
```

[RexEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DURofv/6)

[Also check this Q7A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25910869/548225)

Comment: sorry .. I updated the question that the currency symbol can be any symbol not USD always