# Regex to find the pattern and keep the middle part in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to find a pattern in a string and only keep the middle part if the pattern matches.

The pattern is below:

(space)(↳)(space)(any characters, numbers symbols etc)(space)(-)(space)(currency symbol, could be £$ etc)(1 or many digits)(.)(2 digits)

↳ Add milk - £0.25

If the pattern matches I want to keep (any characters, numbers symbols etc) and discard everything else.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use parentheses `()` in your regex to denote sub-matches. When you run `.exec()`, the results will contain these sub-matches. Details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s↳\s(.+)\s-\s([\$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]\d+\.\d{2})` should work. The long, horrible part in the middle is to find the currency symbol, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27175364/8230810).

Piece by piece:

- `\s` matches a whitespace character
- `↳` matches that character exactly
- `\s` matches a whitespace character
- `(.*)` is your first capture group, and catches everything until the next part of the Regex is matched. `.*` means any character, any number of times.
- `\s-\s` matches a whitespace followed by a dash and another whitespace
- `([\$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]\d+\.\d{2})` catches the currency and digits:

  - `[\$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]` matches a currency character
  - `\d+\.\d{2}` matches one or more digit, followed by a full stop and two more digits

In context:

```js
let regex = /\s↳\s(.+)\s-\s([\$\xA2-\xA5\u058F\u060B\u09F2\u09F3\u09FB\u0AF1\u0BF9\u0E3F\u17DB\u20A0-\u20BD\uA838\uFDFC\uFE69\uFF04\uFFE0\uFFE1\uFFE5\uFFE6]\d+\.\d{2})/;

let testText = " ↳ Add milk - £0.25";
let matches = regex.exec(testText);

console.log("Test text = \"" + matches[0] + "\"");
console.log(matches[1]);
console.log(matches[2]);
```

If you only want to match on a couple of currencies, say `£` or `$`, you will make your life much easier and the regex will look much less ugly.

Comment: Sweet! Exactly what I wanted. Modified it slightly to cater some extra circumstances but works well. Cheers mate.